# How can projectivism explain the ban on mixed worlds?

Tags: ethics, metaethics

The following is from section 4.2(b) of Miller's *Introduction to Contemporary Metaethics*.

Supervenience says that *if two acts, events, or situations share the same naturalistic properties, then they share the same moral properties.* Put more formally: *if a and b are N, then a and b are M* for some collection N and M of naturalistic and moral properties respectively.

Consider the following possible worlds:

- World W1: *b is N, but b is not M.*
- World W2: *a is N and a is M, c is M but c is not M.*

Supervenience allows W1, but 'bans' W2. Miller -paraphrasing Blackburn- explains that realists have trouble explaining why worlds such as W2 -called 'mixed worlds'- are banned, while projectivists can explain such ban easily:

---

[image]
[image]

**What is the argument -in favor of projectivism- in the last paragraph above?** Part of me suspects the argument is as follows:

- (1) A guide to practical decision making must presuppose supervenience.
- (2) Morality is a guide to practical decision making.
- Thus: Morality must presuppose supervenience.

yet such argument leaves unexplained why (1) and (2) hold to begin with.

Comment: 1 is not a premise and 2 is too strong. For 1, if lists of identical N properties endorse different choices as moral they cannot prescribe any for us to follow. For 2, morality is more than a guide to action, but it must provide one on pain of irrelevance.